# Forms - Save Draft and unique user access code to Resume (on any computer)

Tags: forms, webforms

Is it possible for the site users to get a unique access code, so that they can resume the form from any computer?

I am currently using the Webform module for its "Save Draft" feature and am wondering if it is also able to provide an access code ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always have users register accounts, use their passwords as the access code, and then use one of the revision management modules (Workbench, Revisioning/Workflow, etc.) to handle draft/publishing.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a quicker way to get the access code? The client doesn't want to deter users by having to register...

Comment: You could add on to the webform module yourself with custom code, but that would probably be pretty complicated in this case.

Comment: Cheers for that